# Svn checkout @ in path

Tags: batch-file, svn

I've got the strange behavior in `svn checkout` for checkout folder with `@` char in folder name

If I do

```
svn.exe checkout "file:///d:/test/test_repo" "D:\test\@path"
```

then I got checkout in `D:\test@path` folder, not in `D:\test\@path`

Why?

[Doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) say about special @ meaning in `URL[@REV]` part, not in `path` part.

**Update**

Simple

```
md "D:\test\@path"
```

creates the `D:\test\@path`filder, so @ is not batch-special macro.

**Update - 2**

`svn.exe" checkout "file:///d:/test/test_repo" "D:\test\\@path"` - same result.

I use svn v1.8

Comment: Try to double the backslash before the `@`...

Comment: Have you tried `svn.exe checkout "file:///d:/test/test_repo" "D:\test\\@path"`

Comment: I was try - doesn't help